# How to call a json webservice through android

Tags: java, android, web-services, json

I need to access a .Net web service in Rest format using JSON. I m
pretty new to this concept and very much confused about how this
works....
Any one who can give an overview of this. I need the steps that I
need to follow to use JSON. Right now my doubt is how to use JSON to
grab to output.

Comment: check this: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/ http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/ http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: check this post hope you get some idea/help [http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service](http://www.androidsnippets.com/retrieve-json-from-a-rest-web-service) [http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/)

Comment: check this:
[Comsuming WCF Services With Android](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make JSON Request from android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324131/make-json-request-from-android)

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/03/androind-json-parser.html http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/ http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-jsonparsing-tutorial.html http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest way to parse `Json` web servie

```
    String str="url";
    try{
        URL url=new URL(str);
        URLConnection urlc=url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bfr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line=bfr.readLine())!=null)
        {
        JSONArray jsa=new JSONArray(line);
        for(int i=0;i<jsa.length();i++)
           {
           JSONObject jo=(JSONObject)jsa.get(i);
                        title=jo.getString("deal_title");  //tag name "deal_title",will return value that we save in title string
                    des=jo.getString("deal_description");
       }
    }
    catch(Exeption e){
    }
```

Mention Internet permission in android manifest

Comment: It doesn't solve any problem, and stopping the conversion when you encounter a null byte is one of the major errors.

Comment: I think its not your problem.But if you know it has some error..feel free to edit.Else give as answer.If like then i will be the first to +1 your answer.It work for me so i posted here

Comment: Then leave it..i donot see any problem.It work in my application.

Comment: Well that's the main thing. Throwing away data after a null byte clearly isn't a problem for you. It might be for someone else.

Comment: CAn you explain how it going to be problem for someone else.And till now its not clear where i throw null byte.can you explain it

Comment: It is a problem if the data is allowed to contain nulls and continues afterwards. Your code would throw the continuation away. You have an unstated assumption that strings in the stream are terminated or delimited by null bytes. It ain't necessarily so.

Comment: But now i have post a easy way to parse Json.Now should +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

[Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) library can parse your json string automatically to object. 
Simple example:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 String[] strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};

 //(Serialization)
 gson.toJson(ints);     ==> prints [1,2,3,4,5]
 gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

 //(Deserialization)
 int[] ints2 = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4,5]", int[].class); 
 ==> ints2 will be same as ints
```

Answer (score 0):

you use the json data as follows:

```
var a=new JSONObject(jsonData);
```

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Use the data from a to constuct the necessary objects and do the necessary with the same

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the Android activity to read from the Web Service and parse the JSON object:

```
public void clickbutton(View v) {
    try {
        // http://androidarabia.net/quran4android/phpserver/connecttoserver.php

        // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        //
        HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
        // p.setParameter("name", pvo.getName());
        p.setParameter("user", "1");

        // Instantiate an HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/sample1/" + 
                     "webservice1.php?user=1&format=json";
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
        try {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
            //
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "1"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);
            // Parse
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = 
                   new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String s = e.getString("post");
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

                map.put("idusers", jObject.getString("idusers"));
                map.put("UserName", jObject.getString("UserName"));
                map.put("FullName", jObject.getString("FullName"));

                mylist.add(map);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

For more details see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php