# App Reading From SQL Server Web Service

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, web-services, soap

I am in the process of creating an Android application which I want to use to execute a web service on my SQL server which in turn runs a stored procedure.

Having never completed a project like this before, I would like to know what the best way to go about this is?

I.e.

1. Displaying the SQL results
2. Reading from the web service
3. Adding password protection

I've developed apps before, but never SQL - related.

From doing some research I noted the need for a web service and created one, it's the process of running my app to read from it which I would like guidance with. Even a link to a helpful tutorial would be great. Thanks.

**EDIT**

To be more specific on the display.

Currently the stored procedure is displayed through crystal reports, however I have no need for 'drill - downs' or any functionality other than to actually view.

Something similar without the functionality would be fine.

Comment: What API technology do you use? REST? SOAP?

Comment: I'm set up for SOAP. But open to any ideas.

Comment: In that case, I'd second wes's suggestion to use ksoap (in fact ksoap2, if i remember correctly). For displaying the results: There are hell of a lot possibilities. You should be a little mor detailed on that, so someone can actually give you a hint.

Comment: @ Fildur I've edited my post, what are your thoughts on password protection?

Comment: Well, in our soap - application, we used a custom user/pass functionality. But that wasn't built on my designs ... So maybe there are better solutions. For the Display: Maybe some simple ListViews are sufficient? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend KSOAP with a SOAP webservice for proof of concept/tech demo http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

or use the built-in JSON parser with a restful/json webservice
[How to call a json webservice through android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076576/how-to-call-a-json-webservice-through-android)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this link](http://neilgoodman.net/2011/12/26/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-1/) can help you, it has a useful video on the subject and detailed information.

Another link [Comsuming WCF Services With Android](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx)

And also maybe this could help: [Android Web Service MyWeather](https://island.byu.edu/unclass/content/android-web-service-app-my-weather-running-and-full-source-code)